# HTML post array variable

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have created an array variable with a php script.

Now I want to post this variable in a form

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $var ?>" value="Enter">
</form>
```

But when I try to print this $var from the test.php page I get an error saying array to string conversion (echo $var).

How can I post this array to another page with a user only presses a form button?

Comment: your `$var` is an array or a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you must pass the array, you will need to change the format to a stringified format. You can use something like `JSON` for this.

```
<input type="submit" name="json_array" value="<?php echo json_encode($var);?>"/>
```

Now in test.php you can access it like so:

```
$var = isset($_POST['json_array']) ? $_POST['json_array'] : false;
if(isset($var)){
    echo '<pre>', print_r(json_decode($var), true),'</pre>';
}
```